# Why line ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey().Key deletes oldest "O" on Console screen?

Tags: c#, console, console.readkey

Trying to make snake game. I am using Console.SetCursorPosition(int x, int y) to draw body parts("O"), 2D array to store "O" previous locations and Console.KeyAvailable to detect direction changes. When a key is pressed that is not in the switch statement, drawing stops for one iteration. When a key is pressed that is in the switch statement, Console erases oldest body part.

Debugger doesn't show the reason. Can anyone help me to understand why is that happening?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.CursorVisible = false;

    while (true)
    {
        ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
        switch (key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                direction = "RIGHT";
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                direction = "LEFT";
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                direction = "DOWN";
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                direction = "UP";
                break;
        }

        breakOut = false;

        switch (direction)
        {
            case "RIGHT":
                for (int i = x; i <= 100; i++)
                {
                    Iterator(i, y);
                    x = i;
                    if (breakOut)
                        break;
                };
                break;
            case "LEFT":
                break;
            case "DOWN":
                for (int i = y; i <= 100; i++)
                {
                    Iterator(x, i);
                    y = i;
                    if (breakOut)
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case "UP":
                break;
        }
    }
}

static void Iterator(int x, int y)
{
    Draw(x, y);

    xSlot = x;
    ySlot = y;

    histPoints[slotCounter, (int)place.x] = xSlot;
    histPoints[slotCounter, (int)place.y] = ySlot;

    if (slotCounter >= length)
    {
        Erase(histPoints[slotCounter - length, (int)place.x], histPoints[slotCounter - length, (int)place.y]);
    }

    slotCounter += 1;

    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        breakOut = true;
        return;
    }

    Sleep();
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the full code. The double switch statement is redundant by the way, you could just put it into one.

Comment: @Innat3 Missing parts just consists of Console.SetCursorPosition() and Console.Write(). Oh, and Sleep() is Thread.Sleep(500).

Comment: set a default value for `direction`